# AppScript Select active range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so i am trying to when i select any column form the row, returns me the column E value, some one know how?

i don't know if i made me clear, but the idea is save the value and display after in a sidebar as default value
i have onde function who does something similar, but i don't know how works

```
function notifyReporterForm() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_BUGS);
    var row = ss.getLastRow(), column = 1, numRows = 1, numColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

    var to = values[0][2];
    var user_email = values[0][3];
    var ticketNo = values[0][0];
    var openedDate = values[0][1]
    var details = ''
    var summary = values[0][6]
    var text = values[0][6].split('\n')
    var image_url = values[0][8]
    text.map(row => {
        if(row){
            details += '<p>' + row + '</p>'
        }
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`. If you need further help, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  e.source.toast(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).getValue());
  e.range.setValue(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).getValue());
}
```